# Remote upload file to server B

Tags: plugins, functions, customization, uploads, media

I'm aware this might be some of the hardest coding to do ever, but thought of giving it a try.

Im basically trying to detect all (mp3) filetypes uploaded through the Wordpress media upload and send them offsite, thus have them uploaded to a different server through (ftp connection).

Below is the code i started after hours of research and i think i'm stucked, honestly i don't even know if i'm at a good point. I hope someone who has much more knowledge with Wordpress/PHP can help me archive what i'm trying to do. I'm doing this to save the main server from been overloaded with big file sizes and limit it to images.

I would want the structure uploaded to Server B is: serverB.com/music/Year/month/file.mp3

The year and month should inherit from wordpress post date( 'Y/m' );

After it is uploaded the link that appears in wordpress should be that of serverB.com url to the file.

Thank you. Below is the code i started:

```
<?php
/* 
 * Change upload directory/server for mp3 files 
 * Only works in WordPress 3.3+
 */

add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'music_pre_upload');
add_filter('wp_handle_upload', 'music_post_upload');

function music_pre_upload($file){
add_filter('upload_dir', 'music_remote_upload_dir');
return $file;
}

function music_post_upload($fileinfo){
remove_filter('upload_dir', 'music_remote_upload_dir');
return $fileinfo;
}

function music_remote_upload_dir($path){    
$extension = substr(strrchr($_POST['name'],'.'),1);
if(!empty($path['error']) ||  $extension != 'mp3') { return $path; } // if other     filetype send to default uploads folder.

    /**
     * Change this to match your server
     * You only need to change the those with (*)
     * If marked with (-) its optional 
     */

    $post_date = '/' . date( 'Y/m' );

    $settings = array(
            'host'          =>        'host or IP',       // * the ftp-server hostname
            'user'          =>        'ftp-username',                // * ftp-user
            'pass'          =>        'ftp-pass',       // * ftp-password
            'cdn'           =>        'external-server.com',          // * This have to be a pointed domain or subdomain to the root of the uploads
            'path'          =>        '/music',                    // - ftp-path, default is root (/). Change here and add the dir on the ftp-server
            'date'          =>        $post_date          // Local post date
    );

    /**
     * Host-connection
     * Read about it here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-connect.php
     */

    if(function_exists('ftp_ssl_connect'))
     {

    $connection = ftp_ssl_connect( $settings['host'] );

     }
        else
     {
    $connection = ftp_connect( $settings['host'] );
     }

    /**
     * Login to ftp
     * Read about it here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-login.php
     */

    $login = ftp_login( $connection, $settings['user'], $settings['pass'] );

    /**
     * Check ftp-connection
     */

    if ( !$connection || !$login ) {
        die('Connection attempt failed, Check your settings');
    }

   ftp_pasv($resource, true); // To avoid rectify warning

   if( ftp_put( $connection, $settings['path'] . "/" . $settings['date'] . "/" . $file, FTP_BINARY ) ) {

      echo "successfully uploaded $file\n";

        } else {

      echo "There was a problem while uploading $file\n";
      }

      // close the connection
       ftp_close($conn_id); 



} // End function
```

Comment: I see you have done a good job with the code. Although I'd suggest you a plugin. This basically synchronizes your wp-content/uploads into another remote server through FTP. You may tweak this to your needs. http://wordpress.org/plugins/upload-to-ftp/ Also you may want to consider writing code for file sync using SSH or FTPS as FTP is a risky protocol.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `die('message');` and use that to debug where it fails. Also try and use `ftp://external-server.com` as opposed to just `external-server.com`. Also make sure you use your FTP password. And try it on active mode as opposed to passive mode. When I was trying to upload by FTP that's what I had to do.

Also make sure the password for the FTP is encoded corectly. When I was doing it I had a problem where my password was using a symbol `%`, but when I would submit that in my PHP it wouldnt work, I had to submit that as hex.

Also sometimes it's just a missing semicolon, that's the worst.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bad idea. You are going to break the integrity of your site into several fragments, each on different server and introduce additional failure points, and you might lose the ability to run batch task related to those files.

You say that:

> I'm doing this to save the main server from been overloaded with big file sizes and limit it to images

But that is just not true. Serving static files is one of the easiest tasks a webserver does and there is no "overloading" being related to their size. Assuming that you pay for bandwidth on the other server as well, there is just zero point in doing it.

The only reason to do such a thing is when you need to upload file to a CDN (those that still do not support "pull"), but that you should do in addition to the normal file upload process and not instead of it.